# Cannot browse a local easyphp web server using the local IP address

Tags: easyphp

I am running easyphp with apache version 2.4.18 x86 (32-bit) on Windows 10.
On the PC where easyphp is running, I can connect using either localhost or http://computername, but if I try to connect through the local IP address which is http://192.168.0.10, I get a white page without any error message.

And the most strange thing, if I plug an iPhone (USB) with a shared connexion in the PC (the PC gets 2 network connections), then I can access to http://192.168.0.10 through the PC (still the wifi IP local address and not the iPhone local network address).
If I unplug the iPhone, then it fails again to connect to http://192.168.0.10.

Any explanation ?

Answer (score 2):

So it was a firewall problem.
Evene when desactivating the firewall, the web site was not reachable.
I've added manually the

> EasyPHP16\eds-binaries\httpserver\apache2418vc11x86x160927105506\bin\eds-httpserver.exe

in the Windows firewall rules, and it worked.

The two strange things is that disabling the firewall did not arrange anything, and lanching the webserver did not pop up the firewall dialog.

Hope this helps.